# what is the term "constructor function " in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

What is the term built-in constructor functions in  programing?
What is the importance of constructor?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is the method that builds and returns the instances of your class. In this javascript example, the `Person` function is a constructor:

```js
var Person = function(age) {
  this.age = age;
};

mike = new Person(21);

console.log(mike);
```

In python, the constructor is the `__init__` method of your defined class:

```
class Person():
  def __init__(self, age):
    self.age = age

mike = Person(age=21)

print(mike)
```

In this way, your classes can produce multiple instances of themselves.